# Google Cloud Pricing API - Python

Tags: python, gcloud

I am unable to run the following code. Basically I want to list services and their prices...

````
import requests
import asyncio

class_initiate= billing_v1.services.cloud_catalog.CloudCatalogAsyncClient()
result = asyncio.run(class_initiate.list_services())```


RuntimeError: Task <Task pending coro=<CloudCatalogAsyncClient.list_services() running at local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/billing_v1/services/cloud_catalog/async_client.py:185> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py:158]> got Future <Task pending coro=<UnaryUnaryCall._invoke() running at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/grpc/aio/_call.py:489>> attached to a different loop
````

Comment: Hello, could you please add more context to be able to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

@brownkhusra You may want to create an async main function, and then pass it to the `asyncio.run` method. In this way, you ensured that the entire logic in your application will be run on the same event loop.

```
async def main():
    class_initiate= billing_v1.services.cloud_catalog.CloudCatalogAsyncClient()
    result = await class_initiate.list_services()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this to get prices for specific services.

In my case I looked the price for CPU/RAM in `us-cenytral-1`.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from google.cloud import billing_v1
import asyncio

SERVICE_COMPUTE_DISPLAY_NAME = "Compute Engine"
REGION = "us-central1"
INSTANCE_DESCR = "N2 Custom Instance"


async def main():
    catalog = billing_v1.services.cloud_catalog.CloudCatalogAsyncClient()
    result = await catalog.list_services()
    compute_name = None
    for service in result.services:
        if service.display_name == SERVICE_COMPUTE_DISPLAY_NAME:
            compute_name = service.name
    result = await catalog.list_skus(parent=compute_name)
    for sku in result.skus:
        if REGION in sku.service_regions:
            if sku.description.startswith(INSTANCE_DESCR):
                for rate in sku.pricing_info[0].pricing_expression.tiered_rates:
                    if rate.unit_price.currency_code == "USD":
                        print(sku.description)
                        print(rate.unit_price.nanos / 1_000_000_000)


asyncio.run(main())
```